# Java Spring Actuator Grafana - time taken for a request different between http_server_requests_seconds_max and http_server_requests_seconds::sum/count

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

Quick question regarding two queries for the time taken for an API please.

My SpringBoot app has out of the box http_server_requests_seconds **max, count and sum** metrics.

Therefore, I wanted to build a visual in order to see how much time do I take to answer a request.

With that in mind, I started to search on the web existing queries, and found two, which are both supposed to provide the request duration:

`http_server_requests_seconds_max{_ws_="my_workspace"}`

`irate(http_server_requests_seconds::sum{_ws_="my_workspace"}[5m]) / irate(http_server_requests_seconds::count{_ws_="my_workspace"}[5m])`

Unfortunately, the dashboards show completely different graphs.

May I ask if I use one of the two query wrong please?

Which of the two is the most appropriate query in order to get the time taken for a request?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious difference is that the second example calculates the first derivative of your values (the rate), whereas the first does not.

The second query calculates the average response time over 5 minute intervals, the first query simply shows the maximum value of the timer metric.

An explanation of the different metric types in Prometheus can be found at https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary. `irate` is explained at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#irate